# Battery percentage in 14.04

Tags: battery

How can be added battery percentage to status bar in 14.04? I find some solutions but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show battery status on your panel , All you need do is to click on your battery icon. You will see a drop down list.  Now click on Show percentage in menu bar. More over you can check you battery backup in Minutes.
Click on show Time in Menu Bar.

Lokendra Singh